# Tensorflow import in VSCode fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

I'm having trouble to import TensorFlow in my python application, **BUT** only

- if I'm running my application in VSCode (via the debugger) **OR**
- if I'm running it from the Terminal WITHIN VSCode.
  Everything is working fine if I'm running the application from the Terminal outside of VSCode.

I'm running VSCode on macOS Big Sur Version 11.1 (M1 chipset).
I have python 3.8.2 and TensorFlow installed in a virtual environment.

Here's the steps to reproduce the Error. From the **Terminal outside of VSCode** I run

1. `source env/bin/activate` to activate the virtual environment
2. `python` to launch python. Output to the terminal (as expected): Python 3.8.2 (default, Nov  4 2020, 21:23:28) [...]
3. `import tensorflow as tf`
4. `print(tf.__version__)` This prints "2.4.0-rc0" to the terminal (as expected).

Now, if I repeat the exact same steps 1 and 2 in the built in VSCode terminal, I get the exact same output in 2. However, if I run command 3 and try to import tensorflow, the following error message shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /Volumes/SSD/Jan/Documents/Github/TradingBot/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

It seems like the Terminal within VSCode is not using the same site-packages as the Terminal outside of VSCode, however, running `print(sys.path)` gives the same result.

The same problem happens if I'm trying to run my application within VSCode whereas it is working if I'm running it from the Terminal.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Test both terminals again, but start by running the `zsh` command to open a new shell session. This should make sure you're running both terminals with the same shell environment and setup, so the results should be the same (in theory). I'm curious to see what happens.

Comment: I repeated the test as suggested and ran `zsh` before I did the steps in my original post. No change in result.  As @Ryan suggested, I ran `echo $SHELL` and `which python`, both command yield the same output in internal and external terminal.  Tensorflow was not installed via pip since the M1 compatible version is not available via pip. Therefore, `pip show tensorflow` gives an Error message in internal as well as external Terminal @MollyWang

Comment: @pancakeNbacon. Then you can turn to the current activated environment in integrated Terminal to check if there's `tensorflow` in the folder **site-packages**, if not, copy the module into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this problem existed in the first place but I now have it resolved by installing python 3.8 via the ARM build of mini-conda.

Here are the steps.

1. Download mini-conda from here https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-10-29-macos-arm64/ and install it.
2. After installation, create a new Conda environment `conda create --name python38 python=3.8`. This will install the ARM version of python 3.8
3. Activate the new environment `conda activate python38`
4. Create a new virtual environment for your project. `python -m venv myEnv`
5. Download and unpack the ARM version of tensorflow https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases
6. Run the included script to install tensorflow. `/Volumes/SSD/Jan/Downloads/tensorflow_macos/install_venv.sh --prompt` and point it to your newly created virtual environment of step 4.

With these steps, tensorflow could be correctly imported.

Some more reference which pointed me to this solution:
https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/8
https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

Try Python 3.7. Many people have complained tensorflow not working on 3.8, but working on 3.7. Also, try downloading it from the google tensorflow web page.

Comment: I have to use the python / tensorflow version that works with the Apple M1 silicone. Therefore, v3.8 is currently my only option.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing off of Jay Mody in the comments above. I would first check that the shells you use in VS code is the same as the shell you are using in the non-VS code terminal.

Try the following shell commands:

```
echo $SHELL
```

If you get the same output, then I would suggest making sure the exact same python executables are being used. Try typing this in both of the shells:

```
which python
```

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, open an integrated Terminal, after activating the environment, run

```
pip show tensorflow
```

to check if the module exists in the current environment. If not, reinstall it.